# Blade template. Understanding manual or examples for use with several sections

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I can't looking for solution or understanding solution when I try use blade (laravel 4.2) for use with several sections.

For normal use (home extendes layout) not problem.

views/home.blade.php

```
 @extends('layout')

 @section('content')
     Show content of home page
 @endsection
```

view/layout.blade.php

```
<html>
    <!-- Code html such head, template header... -->
    ...

    @yield('content')  

    <!-- Rest code html such footer -->
    ... 
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I like move Rest code (footer) to another template file footer.blade.php I don't understand and try several ways.

view/footer.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('footer')
   <hr>

   <footer>
      <p>&copy; Tamainout Hébergement SARL 2015</p>
   </footer>
   </div>
@endsection
```

and change views/home.blade.php

```
<html>
    <!-- Code html such head, template header... -->
    ...

    @yield('content')  

    @yield('footer')
    <!-- Rest code html such footer -->
    ... 
    </body>
</html>
```

But file footer.blade.php it isn't processed by laravel.

Apreciate some help

NOTE: I put code on [github, abkrim/blade (only files envolved)](https://github.com/abkrim/blade/tree/master)

Comment: Did you use extend in the footer.blade.php? @extends('layout')

Comment: Yes. I corrected code on post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error in the `views/home.blade.php`.
Try:

```
@yield('footer')
```

instead of

```
@yield(footer')
```

**EDIT:**

include `footer.blade.php` in the `layout.blade.php` and remove `extends` from `footer.blade.php`

**views/home.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    Show content of home page
@endsection
```

**views/footer.blade.php:**

```
<hr>
<footer>
    <p>&copy; Tamainout Hébergement SARL 2015</p>
</footer>
</div>
```

**views/layout.blade.php:**

```
@yield('content')
@include('footer')
```

Comment: Add @yield('footer')  to the layout.blade.php

Comment: Did you add to layout.blade.php @yield('footer') ?

Comment: + add folder with dot separator to include

Comment: I put code on github  abkrim/blade https://github.com/abkrim/blade.git (only put app/views/*.blade.php)

Comment: i added pull request, and modified my answer

Comment: A lot of thanks... a simple include. uff. laravel doc it's confuse.